# Minimize the max distance, 1D array

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Problem:

Given a group of numbers of length n (sorted), each number is the location of a house in a 1D line "city".

Given a number k<=n, you need to place k "supermarkets" on the 1D city.

For every element in A, the min distance is defined as the minimum distance between A and a supermarket: |a-c|.

The cost of a city is defined as the max of all min distances.

You need to find what the minimum (optimal) cost would be for a given A of length n, and k<=n.

I can't find a solution for this problem. The solution should use dynamic programming. I'm thinking of how to write the recursive formula, and I think I already came out with the base cases:

if k = n then obviously the result will be 0 since you can place each supermarket in a city

if k = 1, I think the solution should be: (A[n] - A[1])/2.

But I can't come up with the actual formula (and the whole actual dynamic program). Also, I can't seem to find a "title" to this answer, I didn't find any other example of this exact answer online.

Comment: What do you mean by MailBoxes? I believe you're referring to supermarkets? The supermarkets can be everywhere you want on the 1D line - you're the one who needs to place them to get the optimal cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this recursive function for the problem:

- if there are more stands than houses, the answer is 0
- if there is only one stand, so we place it in the middle between the edges

Othrwise:

For all the indexes from i to j, we calculate the maximum between all of them, and then the min.

[image]

Comment: welcome to SO. Your answer could be useful, but only if you add a bit of explanation to it

Answer (score 1):

To minimize the maximum distance from k supermarkets, you divide the houses into consecutive groups so that you minimize the maximum distance between the starting and ending houses in each group.  Then you just put a supermarket in the middle of each group.

Solving the problem this way makes it much easier for dynamic programming, since it removes the continuous variable of supermarket position.

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you're saying, but I don't see how to turn this into a recursive function.

Comment: Let SOLUTION(n,k) be the solution for the given k and the first n houses.  If you have SOLUTION(x,y) for all x<n and y<=k then you can calculate SOLUTION(n,k) by trying the different possible lengths for the last group that includes house n.

Comment: Hi, I came out with a recursive function which I think works. I checked it with a few inputs and it worked, what do you think? It's all of work and very high complexity. Do you think I could improve it somehow?

Comment: SOLUTION(n,k) = min_for_all_i<n{ min(SOLUTION(n-i,k-1), (A[n]-A[n-i])/2) }  is better.  But I wouldn't actually use DP for this problem.  I would use binary search over the possible segment sizes to find the smallest segment size that works.